# Add style to an element based on a Model value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add a simple inline style to my div tag if a certain criteria is met.

I am able to apply the "disabled" class successfully, but I can't get my cursor style to show up.

```
<div class="item  @(item.AvailableTimeSlots == "0" ? "disabled" : "")" @(item.AvailableTimeSlots == "0" ? "style='cursor: default;'" : "")>
```

any pointers?

Comment: You are specifying the default cursor for a `div`. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: I would expect it to put that style declaration into the element, and it's not.  Through other classes, div is a pointer - I want to disable it and remove the pointer attribute without getting into the master class.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was asking, since the default behavior would **be** a pointer, and I wasn't sure if you had checked the source to see that the style attributed had been added.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing - I've never done this before but from the code above I "believed" at a minimum the style declaration would get added to the div.  I was just trying to figure out if there was a way I could do this as detailed - but I can use James example below for my current problem.

Comment: I'm wondering why `AvailableTimeSlots` is a string (not an integer), but since `disabled` is being rendered I'm assuming that the property type is `string`. Other than that, it looks like it should work. You might try simplifying the expression further to debug it, e.g. removing the check for `disabled` (just to simplify things for the parser).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working Snippet**

```
<div class="item  @("0" == "0" ? "disabled" : "")" @Html.Raw("0" == "0" ? "style='cursor: default;'" : "")>
```

Adding `Html.Raw()` fixed the problem for me. Without it, you end up with something like:

```
<div class="item  disabled" style=&#39;cursor: default;&#39;>
```

I tried a few different browsers, and each gave different results when inspecting the DOM. IE8 mangles it; Chrome incorrectly reworks it; IE9 appears to correctly make it well-formed.

Few notes:

- @James' solution that removes inline styles is a good one. The current code is really hard to read, and inline styles are rarely a good idea anyway.
- It looks like `item.AvailableTimeSlots` should be an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

> Any pointers?

It's always best to try avoid inline-styles whenever you can. I would advise you move your `cursor` code into it's own CSS class & work purely with classes e.g.

**CSS**

```
.default {
    cursor: default;
}
.disabled {
    ...
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    var itemCLass = @item.AvailableTimeSlots == "0" ? "disabled" : "default";
}
<div class="item @itemClass" />
```

Comment: If you read it carefully, the style isn't inside `class`. It's just really confusing (agree with your advice on breaking out the code).

Comment: @TimMedora your spot on, I had to look *really* close to spot that. Thanks

Comment: James - correct, class definition works.  I added it similar to how you detailed above, and it worked well.  I'm trying to figure out how to put in a style attributes, though, and still not sure why it didn't get put in.